# Concatenate strings from different levels of list

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

After a lot of trouble I've finally come pretty close to what I want to do. I now have a list that looks like this:

```
{"turen", {{"as", {{"lä", {}}}}, {"al", {{"säd", {}}, {"jäs", {}}}}, {"aj", {{"lä", {}}, {"säl", {}}, {"säd", {}}, {"läs", {}}}}, {"sa", {{"lä", {}}}}, 
  {"la", {{"säd", {}}, {"jäs", {}}}}, {"lä", {{"as", {}}, {"aj", {}}, {"sa", {}}, {"ja", {}}}}, {"ja", {{"lä", {}}, {"säl", {}}, {"säd", {}}, {"läs", {}}}}, 
  {"sal", {}}, {"säl", {{"aj", {}}, {"ja", {}}}}, {"säd", {{"al", {}}, {"aj", {}}, {"la", {}}, {"ja", {}}}}, {"läs", {{"aj", {}}, {"ja", {}}}}, 
  {"dal", {{"jäs", {}}}}, {"jäs", {{"al", {}}, {"la", {}}, {"dal", {}}}}, {"sälj", {}}, {"själ", {}}, {"läsa", {}}, {"ädla", {}}, {"dals", {}}, {"jäsa", {}}, 
  {"sälja", {}}, {"ädlas", {}}}}
```

Now the last thing I need to do is pick out all strings on the fourth level and concatenate them with their ancestors. There aren't any fourth level elements in my example list because those lists are huge. But imagine there is. If I know how to do it for two levels I can probably do it for three or four as well.

For example, if I concatenate up to the second level I should get a list that starts like

```
{"turen as lä","turen al säd" ...}
```

Comment: There is apparently some confusion as to your requirements.  Are the answers below working as desired or do you need what rm-rf describes in the comments below mine?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I was being vague, but in the end I got good solutions that work for me anyway. I may have had in mind something like what rm-rf said but I don't particularly need it. So it's not a necessary criteria for a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you really want is a recursive traversal function, since what you constructed is a form of a prefix tree. Here is one possibility:

```
ClearAll[traverse];
traverse[prev_List, {s_String, {sub__}}] :=
  Map[traverse[{prev, s}, #] &, {sub}];

traverse[prev_List, {s_String, {}}] := 
  StringJoin[Riffle[Flatten[{prev, s}], " "]];

traverse[tree_List] := Flatten[traverse[{}, tree]];
```

The usage is

```
traverse[tree]
```

where `tree` is your nested list above. The result is a list of strings you are after:

```
(* {turen as lä,turen al säd,turen al jäs,<<34>>,turen sälja,turen ädlas} *)
```

Comment: I see that you interpreted this differently (and probably correctly).  Try try again...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Somehow we have different results. In my case, there are more strings, but all of them contain 3 parts (for this particular case). You have less strings but some of them containing more parts.

Comment: Yes, after reading the question again I think I got it totally wrong.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard To tell you the truth, I've been disappointed in the methods like those based on many nested `Map`,`Thread` etc. for a long time, as long as treatment of trees and other recursive structures is concerned. The biggest problem with them is that they realize recursion internally, while what is needed is a custom recursion tuned to a very particular data structure. But they work very well as a *part* of a recursive solution, making the code much shorter indeed.

Comment: I think I've got it now.  Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not answering right away. Now which answer do I accept, yours is incredibly short @Mr.Wizard, but Shifrin's works just as well and I'm in no position to say which one's better so I went with the number of up votes. +1 for both of you! Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Second try:

```
dat = {"turen", {{"as", {{"lä", {}}}}, {"al", {{"säd", {}}, {"jäs", {}}}}, {"aj", {{"lä", \
{}}, {"säl", {}}, {"säd", {}}, {"läs", {}}}}, {"sa", {{"lä", {}}}}, {"la", {{"säd", {}}, \
{"jäs", {}}}}, {"lä", {{"as", {}}, {"aj", {}}, {"sa", {}}, {"ja", {}}}}, {"ja", {{"lä", \
{}}, {"säl", {}}, {"säd", {}}, {"läs", {}}}}, {"sal", {}}, {"säl", {{"aj", {}}, {"ja", \
{}}}}, {"säd", {{"al", {}}, {"aj", {}}, {"la", {}}, {"ja", {}}}}, {"läs", {{"aj", {}}, \
{"ja", {}}}}, {"dal", {{"jäs", {}}}}, {"jäs", {{"al", {}}, {"la", {}}, {"dal", {}}}}, \
{"sälj", {}}, {"själ", {}}, {"läsa", {}}, {"ädla", {}}, {"dals", {}}, {"jäsa", {}}, \
{"sälja", {}}, {"ädlas", {}}}};
```

Then:

```
dat //. {{s_, {}} :> s, {x_, y_List} :> Thread[x ~~ " " ~~ y]};

Flatten[Thread /@ %]
```

> ```
> turen as lä
> turen al säd
> turen al jäs
> turen aj lä
> turen aj säl
> turen aj säd
> turen aj läs
> turen sa lä
> turen la säd
> turen la jäs
> turen lä as
> turen lä aj
> turen lä sa
> turen lä ja
> turen ja lä
> turen ja säl
> turen ja säd
> turen ja läs
> turen sal
> turen säl aj
> turen säl ja
> turen säd al
> turen säd aj
> turen säd la
> turen säd ja
> turen läs aj
> turen läs ja
> turen dal jäs
> turen jäs al
> turen jäs la
> turen jäs dal
> turen sälj
> turen själ
> turen läsa
> turen ädla
> turen dals
> turen jäsa
> turen sälja
> turen ädlas
> ```

Comment: Looks like you've nailed it, +1. Generally, I found recursion to be more powerful than rules + `ReplaceRepeated`, but here apparently the latter is enough.  Nice solution!

Comment: I think the question asked for a way to be able to join words up to some level X, not all the way. Or rather, start with an inner string at level X and prepend all its predecessors.

Comment: @rm-rf what is supposed to happen to the deeper elements then?

Comment: My interpretation was that the deeper ones will be ignored. Taking the above example, if they wanted to concatenate for "level 1" with its ancestors (taking `"turen"` to be level 0), then they'd get `{"turen as", "turen al", "turen aj"...}`. For level 2, they'd get the above list without the two word strings (i.e. `"turen själ"`, `"turen jäsa"`,...)